# postgres enum insertion using pg_query

Tags: php, postgresql

I have a table with one field of enum type. I execute the following query using pg_query

```
INSERT INTO users (email, facebook_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, birth_date, password, gender, school_id, timezone, email_verified, role_id) VALUES ('robert@1599309412.com', NULL, 'Robert', '', 'George', '1984-05-20', 'Some password', 'MALE', 1, '0.0', false, 1 );


pg_query($connection, 'INSERT INTO users (email, facebook_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, birth_date, password, gender, school_id, timezone, email_verified, role_id) VALUES (\'robert@2084537193.com\', NULL, \'Robert\', \'\', \'George\', \'1984-05-20\', \'Some password\', \'MALE\', 1, \'0.0\', false, 1 )')
```

but i get error as below.

> PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input value for enum sex: "MALE"
>   LINE 1: ...rt', '', 'George', '1984-05-20', 'Some password', 'MALE', 1,...

Direct execution of query  in postgres client don't give this error.What is solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please make sure cases match. Postgres is not too strict about it (consider the table names), but it might worth a check.
2. Having a gender attribute `enum`'d is unnecessary overhead in my opinion, you're better off having a `male` int column with 1, 0 values and maybe null for unknown/not specified. With values greater than 1 it's still future-proof just in case a new gender appears. :)
3. If you really are attached to enums, you might want to consider using PDO, because it makes binding values a lot easier and a lot more secure.

Comment: there is no problem with cases... i'm aware of that issue. I guess i'll go with your second point.. make an int column..

Comment: Sorry for not being absolutely constructive, I shared everything I knew.

Comment: PDO? Use pg_query_params(), that's so much easier than PDO. PDO looks like a PITA compared to pg_query_params(). http://nl.php.net/pg_query_params

Comment: I wrote a wrapper function around it, so running your query would look like:

query("INSERT INTO users (email, facebook_id, first_name, middle_name, last_name, birth_date, password, gender, school_id, timezone, email_verified, role_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ? ...)", 'robert@1599309412.com', NULL, 'Robert', '', 'George', '1984-05-20', 'Some password', 'MALE', 1, '0.0', false, 1);